# Reinjecting modified packets in netfilter module

Tags: c++, linux, udp, iptables, netfilter

I have used [netfiler_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/) to create a `NFQUEUE` module for `iptables` that handles all outgoing `UDP` packets.

I want to modify all `UDP` packets that match a certain pattern, and reinject them into the network.

Here is some example code:

```
...

static int Callback( nfq_q_handle *myQueue, struct nfgenmsg *msg, nfq_data *pkt, void *cbData) {
  uint32_t id = 0;
  nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *header;

  if ((header = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(pkt))) {
    id = ntohl(header->packet_id);
  }

  // Get the packet payload
  unsigned char *pktData;
  int len = nfq_get_payload(pkt, &pktData);

  // The following is an example. 
  // In reality, it involves more parsing of the packet payload.
  if (len && pktData[40] == 'X') {
    // Modify byte 40
    pktData[40] = 'Y';
  }

  // Pass through the (modified) packet.
  return nfq_set_verdict(myQueue, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
}

...

int main(){

  ...

  struct nfq_handle nfqHandle;
  nfq_create_queue(nfqHandle,  0, &Callback, NULL)

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

The modified packet does not get reinjected into the stream. How would I inject the modified version of the packet?

Comment: The example code is purely an example, regard it as psuedo-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. First:

```
return nfq_set_verdict(myQueue, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
```

should be:

```
return nfq_set_verdict(myQueue, id, NF_ACCEPT, len, pktData);
```

That tells it you want to send a modified packet. (you might need some type casting)

Second, you just modified the packet. The IP stack isn't helping you out any more at this point, so you'll need to recompute the UDP checksum for that packet, *or* zero it out so the other end won't even check it.

The UDP checksum will live in bytes `0x1A` and `0x1B` of your packet, so this will zero them out:

```
pktData[0x1a] = 0;
pktData[0x1b] = 0;
```

and then your packet will go through.

Comment: How would I recompute the checksum in this situation?

Comment: More specifically, how can I use a generic checksum calculation function and insert it into those two byes?

Comment: You can't use a generic one, you've got to use the UDP checksum function. It's described in RFC768, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768 and on Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Checksum_computation

Comment: And what would be the point of calculating a checksum in the first place if the packet goes through without doing so?

Comment: It was originally included to ensure that the data arrives without corruption from intermediate links. But these days basically every link layer performs checksumming of its own, and it is extremely unlikely there will be corruption even sending the packet across the internet, let alone local links. If you're just working on this for local traffic, and/or pedagogical purposes, there isn't much point to bothering with the checksum.